# Count number of post and total like per user in a range of time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have 2 tables: `members` and `posts`

In table `members`, I have `USERID` for each user. In table `posts`, I have `PID` for each post and `USERID` of the user who created the post. Each post also has `number_of_like`, indicating how many times a post was liked.

```
/*Table: posts*/
----------------

Field              Type              Null    Key     Default         Extra          
-----------------  ----------------  ------  ------  ----------  --------------
PID                bigint(20)        NO      PRI     (NULL)      auto_increment
USERID             bigint(20)        NO              0                         
number_of_like     int(10) unsigned  YES             0                         
number_of_comment  int(10) unsigned  YES             0                         
date_added         date              NO              0000-00-00
```

Now I want to count that: in a range of time `(DATE(date_added) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)`, each user have how many posts and the total like of them. I count by month and week.

Can I do that directly in a query? Or must I use foreach to count for each user, write it to a `stats` table and then SELECT from `stats` when needed?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you :)

**UPDATE**

I need to list all users, regardless of their post count.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    U.USERID,
    COUNT(*),                <- total of posts per user
    SUM(A.number_of_like)    <- total of likes in these posts
FROM users U
LEFT JOIN posts A ON U.USERID = A.USERID
WHERE ISNULL(A.USERID) 
    OR A.date_added > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
GROUP BY A.USERID;
```

I've used [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for the date calculation, other date functions might be possible here, too.

***Update:***

After you've provided the detail you want every user (not only the ones that have posts), I've updated the SQL query above.

Comment: Why do you use DATE_ADD with negative INTERVAL instead of DATE_SUB?

Comment: I've already stated that other date functions might be of use here, too. Choosing between `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` doesn't really matter that much, it is more a matter of stylistic taste. I personally think the +/- is easier to read, since you have to use those in arithmetic context everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've tried this query before, but this only list the users who actually posted at least 1 post (so their USERID exist in table posts). I need to list ALL users, if they have no post, post_count will be 0 ^^. Do we need a JOIN here?

Comment: right, you should do an left outer join from users to posts based on users.id = posts.USERID

Comment: Sorry, this detail wasn't specifically mentioned in the question above. I've updated my reply and added a `LEFT JOIN` and the `WHERE`-condition so now _every_ userid should be returned regardless on having posts or not.

Comment: Thank you @Bjoern. Sorry for not providing full info. I've updated the query, and the result is shown as: http://i.imgur.com/z0RpJ0r.png. `USERID` are from 1 to 26, and I expect the first left column should have each `USERID` per row.

Comment: @Phuong Nguyen Thats what my query should deliver.